# Virtualbox audio stutters when using a Windows 7 Guest

Tags: audio, virtualbox

I have a MacOS Host and I just used the Win7 Image for Virtualbox from Modern.ie and installed it.

The audio stutters and it's very unpleasant to view any media. How can I fix it?

Comment: While it's nice to share solutions, this one is off-topic here and should be rather posted on [su]. I'd recommend flagging for mod attention and asking to move it there.

Answer (score 0):

Select ICH AC97 as Audio controller and download the Realtek driver from [this page](http://www.realtek.com.tw/Downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=14&PFid=23&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false)